# Append contents to end of file at end of each nested loop iteration?

Tags: powershell

```
$words = Get-Content D:\words.txt
$row = Get-Content D:\row.txt
$j=0

 Get-Content D:\row.txt | ForEach-Object {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $words.Count; $i++){
   Write-Host ($row.Getvalue($j)+ ". " + $words.GetValue($i))
   }
   $j++
   Write-Host ("`n")
} | Set-Content D:\rip.txt
```

```
*OUTPUT*
1. alpha
1. beta
1. charlie
1. delta


2. alpha
2. beta
2. charlie
2. delta


3. alpha
3. beta
3. charlie
3. delta


4. alpha
4. beta
4. charlie
4. delta
```

I wanted to save all the contents of the nested loop into a rip.txt, however it does not save properly. Either there are no contents inside the file or only the 1st row of contents are saved to a file

```
1. alpha
1. beta
1. charlie
1. delta
```

Comment: Your loop is producing no output to the success stream (stdout) it's all going to the information stream (what `Write-Host` sends objects to). Just remove it and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be reduced to this:

```
$words = Get-Content D:\words.txt
Get-Content D:\row.txt | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($word in $words) {
        "$_. $word"
    }
    "`n"
} | Set-Content D:\rip.txt
```

The main issue is the use of `Write-Host` which writes to the [Information Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#information-stream) not to the [Success Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#success-stream).